# VB.Net Memory Issues and Constant New Arrays

Tags: vb.net, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to handle memory in VB.Net. I've been learning as I've been going and I think I'm missing some basic fundamental stuff which is coming back to bite me now with memory issues. The private bytes are steadily increasing until it throws an exception due to memory.

At the moment I'm constantly calling to subroutines which are creating arrays. And I'm constantly calling to them.

Example:

```
Loop
SomethingLikeThis()
Do

Private Sub SomethingLikeThis()
Dim parts As String() = otherstring.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
End Sub
```

If my understanding is correct the DIM is setting aside memory to store that data. If I'm constantly doing this does .net know I'm done with the original allocated space or am I constantly taking up more? If so is there a way I can clear this or do I just create a global array and constantly .clear() and overwrite it rather than setting aside new space for it?

If I understand things properly a parts.clear() would free up the memory when the .net framework runs it's memory cleanup garbage handling. So if I set the DIM earlier (either make it global or pass it around) then .clear() it after each use it might work better?

I'd appreciate any help on this one. I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: If there are just strings in the array, it will be eligible for GC when it goes out of scope (End Sub).  If there are objects created, they are eligible for GC when nothing references them anymore.  If there are resources involved (bitmaps, DB connections, anything generally which has a .Dispose method)m they should be eligible when your code Disposes of them.  There are tools in VS to help refine your code at least as a starting point - Code Analysis and Performance Analysis

Comment: BTW your first para seems unfinished: `The private bytes are steadily increasing until`

Comment: The parts sub is just full of strings which means .net must be doing what I've always assumed it was doing which was freeing that memory up when that routine was done.

Comment: No.  They are *eligible* for GC when the sub ends.  Net will run GC when it sees fit.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's been a long day. It was increasing until it crashed due to running out of memory. I'll give the analysis stuff a go hopefully it can show me specifically which array is holding too much.

Comment: We need to see context for how these strings are used and where `otherstring` is coming from.